# how can I improve my accent sothat it would not be odd for the others?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english, accent

how can I improve my accent sothat it would not be odd for the others?!
everybody told me something! but they did not tell me what i really need to hear!
please help me my friends

how can I improve my accent sothat it would not be odd for the others?!
everybody told me something! but they did not tell me what i really need to hear!
please help me my friends

**Stackoverflow**, **please let me ask!**

Comment: Welcome to the site, Matin. Unfortunately, this question isn't exactly what the site is for. The Stack Exchange network is a Q&A site rather than a discussion forum, so questions must have a verifiable answer, wherase this kind of question is likely to attract many different opinions. The scope of this particular site is questions on a point of learning English. Have a loiter on the site and see the sort of questions that get asked.

Comment: (You might have better luck with this question by looking for an ELL forum site rather than a Q&A site. Good luck!)

Comment: Step 1: listen carefully to how vowels are pronounced. It may take quite a bit of practice to stop speaking them like your native language. One example is a colleague named Philip, who gets annoyed when non-native speakers call him "Feeleep".

Comment: Another point to watch is how you make the **r** sound. In Spanish it is rolled from the tip of the toungue, in French it is rasped from the back of the tongue, and in English is usually quite a soft sound.

Comment: There are plenty of teachers--and, I think, online services--that specialize in teaching such things. But that's not a service we provide for free; we only answer specific individual questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because advice goes on META, not here.